# Is there a way to allow Google Sheets to IMPORTXML that is inside my company's corporate network?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-gsuite

My company is on an enterprise plan and behind a FW. This means I cannot `IMPORT...` in a Google Sheet to any URL inside the corporate network.

Is there way to make it so files in my company's G-Suite organization (example.com) can access my internal corporate network? Like some kind of virtual private network or something?

Comment: You may want to consider opening a support ticket at [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&fl=1) to get better/expert advise on how to go about with this network-related matter.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to whitelist all these hosts in the firewall side for it to work

```
For the following hosts, [N] means any single decimal digit and * means any string not containing a period.

www.google.com:443/HTTPS
accounts.google.com:443/HTTPS
googledrive.com:443/HTTPS
drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.c.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
sheets.google.com:443/HTTPS
slides.google.com:443/HTTPS
talk.google.com:5222/XMPP (needed only for Backup and Sync)
takeout.google.com:443/HTTPS
gg.google.com:443/HTTPS
script.google.com:443/HTTPS
ssl.google-analytics.com:443/HTTPS
video.google.com:443/HTTPS
s.ytimg.com:443/HTTPS
apis.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
*.googleapis.com:443/HTTPS
*.googleusercontent.com:443/HTTPS
*.gstatic.com:443/HTTPS
*.gvt1.com:443/HTTPS
lh[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
[N].client-channel.google.com:443/HTTPS
clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
inputtools.google.com:443/HTTPS
sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
sites.google.com:80/HTTP
sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.googlegroups.com:443/HTTPS
ipv4.google.com:443/HTTPS
ipv4.google.com:80/HTTP
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954)

Comment: This would allow EVERYONE with a G-Suite account to access content INSIDE our corporate network. I want just our organization account (example.com) to have access.

Comment: The documentation states that those hosts are necessary to allow access to all the Drive features. However, to add restrictions to specific users, domains or devices will need to be configured in the Firewall settings. 

For example, you can review this [documentation when you use AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/restrict-access-to-only-specified-users-or-devices) and this one from [CISCO](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa97/configuration/firewall/asa-97-firewall-config/access-idfw.html).

Comment: So it will all depend on the architecture of your Firewall and if the features are available to restrict the host to specific users or devices.

Comment: The documentation is for outbound access to G-Suite services, **not** for inbound requests from G-Suite to the corporate network. Firewall settings do not work for G-Suite organizations. You can create organizations in G-Suite and control access to G-Suite content from there. For example, anything created in my company's G-Suite account is not accessible by others. This is not something a firewall request can help with. It has to be something in the Google Workspace side.